# JMeter - JSON parse error: Unexpected character

Tags: jmeter, api, json

I am trying to add dynamic Post response on one rest API URL(`http:IP:9000/page`) with data as a JSON request in file format, So to add that file in post body I use the command:

```
{__$FileToString(C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\${__eval(${Json_request.txt})},,)}
```

and the JSON file data is:

```
{

"User ID": 204120,

"name": "New User",


"Description": [{"john",204110,"robotics"},

                 {"smith",204111,"AI"},

                 {"Jack",204112,"Machinelearning"}]
"Status": "Post request Successfully"

}
```

But after running this script there is an error in the response body in view results tree:

```
{"timestamp":1574329356300,"status":400,"error":"Bad 
Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
"message":"JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('_' (code 95)): was expecting double-quote to start field name; nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character 
('_' (code 95)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at 
[Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@73210d3e; line: 1, column: 3]","path":"/page"}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Your data is not a valid [JSON](http://json.org/), you can check it yourself using i.e. [online JSON formatter and validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

   [image]
2. You syntax of combination of [__eval()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) and [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) functions is incorrect, you should **wrap** the __FileToString() function into the __eval() and you're doing the opposite thing:

   ```
   ${__eval(${__FileToString(${Json_request.txt},,)})}
   ```

   More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/)

Comment: THanks, it works

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is not valid:

```
1 {
2   "User ID": 204120,
3   "name": "New User",
4   "Description": [{
5       "name": "john",
6       "id": 204110,
7       "type": "robotics"
8   }],
9   "Status": "Post request Successfully"
10 }
```

You need to add a name to the value on lines 5,6,7

Or you need to remove the {} brackets to make it valid

```
"Description": [ "john", 204110, "robotics" ]
```

Also you missed a comma on line 8, at the end of the Description block.

Maybe you should study the JSON format: http://www.json.org/ and use a JSON validator first https://jsonlint.com/